Solana program failing "An account required by the instruction is missing"
I wanted user to transfer some spl token to contract then i want do distribute it later, i have wrote one contract with help of GPT when I try to interact with that contract it throws error im not that good at rust, I'm familiar with EVM
Error
transactionLogs
: 
Array(16)
0
: 
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]"
1
: 
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success"
2
: 
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]"
3
: 
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success"
4
: 
"Program 7KNzQPbmGAN4G45ncYvmCbh3xpdaYzh2iyRbZRtUwkUV invoke [1]"
5
: 
"Program log: Instruction: Deposit"
6
: 
"Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]"
7
: 
"Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success"
8
: 
"Program log: Deposit function called with amount: 1000000"
9
: 
"Program log: Depositor: 461tUdXc9KVB2woxUVzZQWkkCBEGgjmJz7HHK5Wg9gcB"
10
: 
"Program log: Vault: 3XNcYXdfZ5k1C6bFw3JeZD6zeChbbiyfKXkbs75tKo3G"
11
: 
"Program log: User deposit account: GDrEaBQ35fRFdCdYwza1NNZZvCoGitYgLM6zREaN8hMt"
12
: 
"Program log: Mint address: 88vRvJtjbESDcQw8yDwGgu1HAotP6LPikpfp1UjsPy2K"
13
: 
"Unknown program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
14
: 
"Program 7KNzQPbmGAN4G45ncYvmCbh3xpdaYzh2iyRbZRtUwkUV consumed 59893 of 199700 compute units"
15
: 
"Program 7KNzQPbmGAN4G45ncYvmCbh3xpdaYzh2iyRbZRtUwkUV failed: An account required by the instruction is missing"

Frontend
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { AnchorProvider, Program } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { Connection, PublicKey, SystemProgram } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount } from '@solana/spl-token';
import idl from './idl.json'; // Ensure this points to your IDL file

const programId = new PublicKey("7KNzQPbmGAN4G45ncYvmCbh3xpdaYzh2iyRbZRtUwkUV");
const usdcMintAddress = new PublicKey("88vRvJtjbESDcQw8yDwGgu1HAotP6LPikpfp1UjsPy2K"); // SPL Token mint address for testing

const App = () => {
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
  const [program, setProgram] = useState(null);
  const [userTokenAccount, setUserTokenAccount] = useState(null);
  const [phantomWallet, setPhantomWallet] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const runApp = async () => {
      const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com");

      if (window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom) {
        const wallet = window.solana;

        await wallet.connect();
        setPhantomWallet(wallet);

        const newProvider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
          preflightCommitment: "processed",
        });

        setProvider(newProvider);
        const newProgram = new Program(idl, programId, newProvider);
        setProgram(newProgram);

        console.log("Provider and Program initialized");

        // Create or get user's SPL token account
        const userAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
          connection,
          wallet,
          usdcMintAddress,
          wallet.publicKey
        );
        setUserTokenAccount(userAccount.address);
        console.log("User token account:", userAccount.address.toString());
      } else {
        alert("Please install Phantom Wallet.");
      }
    };

    runApp();
  }, []);

  const deposit = async (amount) => {
    if (!program || !userTokenAccount || !phantomWallet) {
      console.error("Program or userTokenAccount not initialized");
      return;
    }

    const decimals = 6; // Adjust according to your SPL token's decimals
    const depositAmount = amount * 10 ** decimals; // Adjust for SPL token decimals

    console.log("Deposit amount:", depositAmount);
    console.log("Program:", depositAmount);

    // Create vault token account for your SPL token
    let vaultAccount;
    try {
      vaultAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        provider.connection,
        phantomWallet,
        usdcMintAddress,
        program.provider.publicKey // Use the program's public key as the vault owner
      );
      console.log("Vault account created/exists:", vaultAccount.address.toString());
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating vault account:", error);
      return;
    }

    // Create user deposit account
    const userDepositAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log("User deposit account generated:", userDepositAccount.publicKey.toString());

    try {
      await program.rpc.deposit(new anchor.BN(depositAmount), {
        accounts: {
          depositor: phantomWallet.publicKey,
          userDeposit: userDepositAccount.publicKey,
          vault: vaultAccount.address,
          usdcMint: usdcMintAddress,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [userDepositAccount],
      });
      console.log("Deposited tokens into the vault!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Transaction failed:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Solana Program Interaction</h1>
      {provider ? <p>Wallet connected!</p> : <p>Connecting wallet...</p>}
      <button onClick={() => deposit(1)}>Deposit 1 SPL Token</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

Contract
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, TokenAccount};
use solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;
use spl_token::instruction::transfer;

declare_id!("7KNzQPbmGAN4G45ncYvmCbh3xpdaYzh2iyRbZRtUwkUV");

#[program]
pub mod deposit_and_release {
    use super::*;

    #[account]
    pub struct UserDeposit {
        pub amount: u64, // Total amount deposited
    }

    #[account]
    pub struct State {
        pub authority: Pubkey,  // Address of the program deployer
        pub token_mint: Pubkey, // Address of the token mint
    }

    pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        authority: Pubkey,
        token_mint: Pubkey,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let state = &mut ctx.accounts.state;
        state.authority = authority;
        state.token_mint = token_mint; // Store the token mint address
        msg!(
            "Initialized state with authority: {:?}, token_mint: {:?}",
            authority,
            token_mint
        );
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn deposit(ctx: Context<Deposit>, amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        msg!("Deposit function called with amount: {}", amount);

        // Validate deposit amount
        if amount < 1_000_000 || amount > 10_000_000 {
            msg!("Invalid deposit amount: {}", amount);
            return Err(ProgramError::Custom(ErrorCode::InvalidDepositAmount as u32));
        }

        let user_deposit = &mut ctx.accounts.user_deposit;
        user_deposit.amount += amount;

        let depositor = &ctx.accounts.depositor;
        let vault = &ctx.accounts.vault;

        msg!("Depositor: {:?}", depositor.key());
        msg!("Vault: {:?}", vault.to_account_info().key); // Updated line
        msg!("User deposit account: {:?}", user_deposit.key());
        msg!("Mint address: {:?}", ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.key());

        // Create the transfer instruction
        let transfer_instruction = transfer(
            &spl_token::id(),
            depositor.key,               // Source: depositor's token account
            vault.to_account_info().key, // Destination: vault's token account (updated)
            depositor.key,               // Owner of the source account
            &[],                         // No multisig
            amount,                      // Amount to transfer
        )?;

        // Use invoke_signed
        invoke_signed(
            &transfer_instruction,
            &[
                depositor.to_account_info(),
                vault.to_account_info(), // Updated line
                ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[], // No seeds
        )?;

        msg!(
            "Transfer successful from depositor to vault. Amount: {}",
            amount
        );
        msg!(
            "Total amount in user deposit account after deposit: {}",
            user_deposit.amount
        );
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn distribute_winnings(
        ctx: Context<Distribute>,
        addresses: Vec<Pubkey>,
        amounts: Vec<u64>,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        msg!("Distribute winnings function called");

        if *ctx.accounts.authority.key != ctx.accounts.state.authority {
            msg!("Unauthorized access by: {:?}", ctx.accounts.authority.key);
            return Err(ProgramError::Custom(ErrorCode::Unauthorized as u32));
        }

        if addresses.len() != amounts.len() {
            msg!(
                "Input addresses and amounts do not match. Addresses: {:?}, Amounts: {:?}",
                addresses,
                amounts
            );
            return Err(ProgramError::Custom(ErrorCode::MismatchedInput as u32));
        }

        let vault = &ctx.accounts.vault;

        for (address, amount) in addresses.iter().zip(amounts.iter()) {
            msg!("Transferring {} tokens to {:?}", amount, address);
            let transfer_instruction = transfer(
                &spl_token::id(),
                vault.to_account_info().key,
                address,
                ctx.accounts.authority.key,
                &[],
                *amount,
            )?;

            invoke_signed(
                &transfer_instruction,
                &[
                    vault.to_account_info(),
                    ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
                ],
                &[],
            )?;
            msg!("Transfer of {} tokens to {:?} successful", amount, address);
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 32 + 32)] // Space for State struct
    pub state: Account<'info, State>, // State account
    #[account(mut)] // Mark user as mutable
    pub user: Signer<'info>, // User signing the transaction
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, // Required for creating accounts
    pub usdc_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Deposit<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub depositor: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init_if_needed, payer = depositor, space = 8 + 8)] // Space for UserDeposit struct
    pub user_deposit: Account<'info, UserDeposit>,
    #[account(mut, constraint = vault.mint == usdc_mint.key())]
    // Ensure vault is associated with the correct mint
    pub vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub usdc_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Distribute<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, // Vault to hold the new token
    pub authority: Signer<'info>, // Authority to execute the distribution
    pub state: Account<'info, State>, // State account holding authority
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Invalid deposit amount.")]
    InvalidDepositAmount,
    #[msg("Input addresses and amounts do not match.")]
    MismatchedInput,
    #[msg("Unauthorized access.")]
    Unauthorized,
}

I don't know where I'm making mistake, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

The error means that an account required by the transfer instruction is missing.
From your contract code, it's the spl_token program. Adding it should fix it.
Not required but, you'd benefit greatly from using the anchor-spl typed methods for SPL Tokens, e.g to transfer a token
use anchor_spl::{
    token::{transfer_checked, TransferChecked as SPLTransferChecked},
};

let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();

let cpi_accounts = SPLTransferChecked {
    from: ctx.accounts.depositor.to_account_info(),
    mint: ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.to_account_info(),
    to: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
    authority: ctx.accounts.depositor.to_account_info(),
};

let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
    cpi_program.clone(),
    cpi_accounts,
);

transfer_checked(
    cpi_ctx,
    amount,
    ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.decimals,
)?;

